# maximum number of nested entities?

Tags: solr

I’ve got a problem during the dataimport. I’m using solr 3.3 on a Tomcat 7 and I’m trying to get the data from a MS SQL Server 2008.
I’ve done the setup of the DHI without any problems and the DHI worked already.
This was the entity I used for the import:

```
<entity name="hhh" query="Select
                tbl_hhh.ID,
  tbl_hhh.ID_breed,
  tbl_hhh.ID_Color,
  tbl_hhh.ID_sex,
  tbl_verkauf.VD,
  tbl_verkauf.Basisfornegation,
  tbl_verkauf.Price_Euros AS Price,
  tbl_verkauf.Buisiness,
  tbl_verkauf.LastEdit,
  tbl_verkauf.Date,
  tbl_hhh.Temperament,
  tbl_hhh.Age AS Age,
  tbl_hhh.Name,
  C_tbl_weight.weight_g,
  C_tbl_handshigh.handshigh_cm,
  tbl_hhh.ID_description,
  f1.Name As f1Name      ,
  m1.Name As m1Name     ,
  ff2.Name As ff2Name    ,
  fm2.Name As fm2Name    ,
  fff3.Name As fff3Name    ,
  FFM3.Name As FFM3Name    ,
  FMF3.Name As FMF3Name    ,
  FMM3.Name As FMM3Name    ,
  MF2.Name As MF2Name    ,
  MM2.Name As MM2Name    ,
  MFF3.Name As MFF3Name    ,
  MFM3.Name As MFM3Name    ,
  MMF3.Name As MMF3Name    ,
  MMM3.Name As MM3Name   
From
  tbl_verkauf Inner Join
  tbl_hhh On tbl_verkauf.ID_Hhh = tbl_hhh.ID Inner Join
  C_tbl_weight On tbl_hhh.ID_Weight = C_tbl_weight.ID Inner Join       

  C_tbl_handshigh On tbl_hhh.ID_handshigh = C_tbl_handshigh.ID 

  left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as f1 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_F1 = f1.ID   
                     left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as m1 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_M1 = m1.ID   
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as ff2 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FF2 = ff2.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as fm2 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FM2 = fm2.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as fff3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FFF3 = fff3.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as FFM3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FFM3 = FFM3.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as FMF3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FMF3 = FMF3.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as FMM3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FMM3 = FMM3.ID                      left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MF2 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MF2 = MF2.ID                      left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MM2 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MM2 = MM2.ID        left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MFF3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MFF3 = MFF3.ID left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MFM3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MFM3 = MFM3.ID left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MMF3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MMF3 = MMF3.ID 
  left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MMM3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MMM3 = MMM3.ID   
 ">
</entity>
```

Now I’ve added some sub-entities:

```
<entity name="hhh" query="Select
                tbl_hhh.ID,
  tbl_hhh.ID_breed,
  tbl_hhh.ID_Color,
  tbl_hhh.ID_sex,
  tbl_verkauf.VD,
  tbl_verkauf.Basisfornegation,
  tbl_verkauf.Price_Euros AS Price,
  tbl_verkauf.Buisiness,
  tbl_verkauf.LastEdit,
  tbl_verkauf.Date,
  tbl_hhh.Temperament,
  tbl_hhh.Age AS Age,
  tbl_hhh.Name,
  C_tbl_weight.weight_g,
  C_tbl_handshigh.handshigh_cm,
  tbl_hhh.ID_description,
  f1.Name As f1Name      ,
  m1.Name As m1Name     ,
  ff2.Name As ff2Name    ,
  fm2.Name As fm2Name    ,
  fff3.Name As fff3Name    ,
  FFM3.Name As FFM3Name    ,
  FMF3.Name As FMF3Name    ,
  FMM3.Name As FMM3Name    ,
  MF2.Name As MF2Name    ,
  MM2.Name As MM2Name    ,
  MFF3.Name As MFF3Name    ,
  MFM3.Name As MFM3Name    ,
  MMF3.Name As MMF3Name    ,
  MMM3.Name As MM3Name   
From
  tbl_verkauf Inner Join
  tbl_hhh On tbl_verkauf.ID_Hhh = tbl_hhh.ID Inner Join
  C_tbl_weight On tbl_hhh.ID_Weight = C_tbl_weight.ID Inner Join       

  C_tbl_handshigh On tbl_hhh.ID_handshigh = C_tbl_handshigh.ID 

  left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as f1 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_F1 = f1.ID   
                     left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as m1 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_M1 = m1.ID   
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as ff2 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FF2 = ff2.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as fm2 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FM2 = fm2.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as fff3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FFF3 = fff3.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as FFM3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FFM3 = FFM3.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as FMF3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FMF3 = FMF3.ID 
                       left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as FMM3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_FMM3 = FMM3.ID                      left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MF2 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MF2 = MF2.ID                      left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MM2 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MM2 = MM2.ID        left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MFF3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MFF3 = MFF3.ID left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MFM3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MFM3 = MFM3.ID left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MMF3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MMF3 = MMF3.ID 
  left outer Join  
  A_tbl_ancestry as MMM3 On tbl_hhh.ID_ancestry_MMM3 = MMM3.ID   
 ">

<entity name="Miscellaneous" processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor" query="Select
               M_tbl_hhh_miscellaneous.ID_Miscellaneous
From
  M_tbl_hhh_miscellaneous
  where deleted = 'false' and  M_tbl_hhh_miscellaneous.ID_Hhh = '${hhh.ID}'

 ">
        <field column="ID_Miscellaneous" name="ID_Miscellaneous" />

      </entity>


      <entity name="Success_Dressage" processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor" query="Select
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.Name As Dressage_success
From
  L_tbl_success Inner Join
  L_tbl_discipline On L_tbl_success.ID_discipline = L_tbl_discipline.ID
  Inner Join
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline On L_tbl_discipline.ID_cattegory_discipline =
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline.ID Inner Join
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local On
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.ID_cattegory_discipline =
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline.ID
Where
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.ID_local = '2' And
  L_tbl_success.ID_Hhh = '${hhh.ID}' And
  L_tbl_success.deleted = 'false' And
  L_tbl_discipline.ID_cattegory = '3'
Group By
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.Name 

 ">


      </entity>

      <entity name="Success_Jumping" processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor" query="Select
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.Name As Jumping_success
From
  L_tbl_success Inner Join
  L_tbl_discipline On L_tbl_success.ID_discipline = L_tbl_discipline.ID
  Inner Join
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline On L_tbl_discipline.ID_cattegory_discipline =
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline.ID Inner Join
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local On
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.ID_cattegory_discipline =
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline.ID
Where
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.ID_local = '2' And
  L_tbl_success.ID_Hhh = '${hhh.ID}' And
  L_tbl_success.deleted = 'false' And
  L_tbl_discipline.ID_cattegory = '4'
Group By
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.Name 

 ">
      </entity>

      <entity name="Success_Eventing" processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor" query="Select
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.Name As Eventing_success
From
  L_tbl_success Inner Join
  L_tbl_discipline On L_tbl_success.ID_discipline = L_tbl_discipline.ID
  Inner Join
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline On L_tbl_discipline.ID_cattegory_discipline =
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline.ID Inner Join
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local On
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.ID_cattegory_discipline =
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline.ID
Where
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.ID_local = '2' And
  L_tbl_success.ID_Hhh = '${hhh.ID}' And
  L_tbl_success.deleted = 'false' And
  L_tbl_discipline.ID_cattegory = '5'
Group By
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.Name 

 ">
      </entity>

      <entity name="Success_Draghunting" processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor" query="Select
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.Name As Draghunting_success
From
  L_tbl_success Inner Join
  L_tbl_discipline On L_tbl_success.ID_discipline = L_tbl_discipline.ID
  Inner Join
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline On L_tbl_discipline.ID_cattegory_discipline =
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline.ID Inner Join
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local On
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.ID_cattegory_discipline =
    L_tbl_cattegory_discipline.ID
Where
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.ID_local = '2' And
  L_tbl_success.ID_Hhh = '${hhh.ID}' And
  L_tbl_success.deleted = 'false' And
  L_tbl_discipline.ID_cattegory = '6'
Group By
  L_tbl_cattegory_discipline_local.Name 

 ">

</entity>
</entity>
```

The first 3 also worked but from the time I added the 4th the debug-window of the dhi keep empty. It does not matter which of the entities I delete or add, the 4th one is always the problem.
I had a look into the log, there was only the message:

14.10.2011 13:39:33 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter verifyWithSchema
INFO: LastEdit is a required field in SolrSchema . But not found in DataConfig

Is there a limit of sub-entities? Or another reason why the debug-import is not running?

Thanks a lot!!!